# Pass data from Partitioner to JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to use sping batch Partitioner for my chunk processing steps. I would like to pass data from Partitioner to my itemreader step using stepexecutioncontext, but unable to do so.

Following are my configurations -

Partitioner -

```
public class MyPartitioner implements Partitioner{
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize)
{
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    List<String> codes = getCodes();

    for (String code : codes)
    {
        ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
        context.put("code", code);
        partitionMap.put(code, context);
    }
    return partitionMap;
}}
```

Job config.xml -

```
<bean id="MyPartitioner" class="com.MyPartitioner" />
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.MyProcessor" scope="step" />
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step" >
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  <property name="sql" value="select * from mytable WHERE code = '#{stepExecutionContext[code]}' "/>
  <property name="rowMapper">
      <bean class="com.MyRowMapper" scope="step"/>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" >
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true"/>
</bean>

  <bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql" value="some sql" />

    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<batch:step id="Step1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="itemReader"  processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="200"/>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
<batch:job id="myjob">
    <batch:step id="mystep">
        <batch:partition step="Step1" partitioner="MyPartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="20" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

This code works fine when ran as standalone application, but when run inside a server application, the itemreader step reads query as

select * from mytable WHERE code = '#{stepExecutionContext[code]}' instead of

select * from mytable WHERE code = 'mycode'.

Please suggest me what am I doing wrong or is there any other configuration needs to be done for this to work inside a server application?

Thanks

Comment: I see that you put value in map as `Code` and read with `code`, have you tried to use same case when putting stuff to map and reading (case sensitivity)? Just tried with my code which has unit test and it fails when I use case insensitive data

Comment: Sorry, it was typo while copy pasting on here, the "code" which has been put into map is same as the one read in itemreader "code".  Following are the correct lines -context.put("code", code);
 partitionMap.put(code, context);

Comment: Can you try reformat your sql like this: `select * from mytable WHERE code = #{stepExecutionContext['code']}`, so to put quotes around code and not around variable which needs to be wired by spring

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I tried this as well but the result is same, now the query reads like this - select * from mytable WHERE code = #{stepExecutionContext['code']}

Comment: And can you try it like this, wrapp it in CDATA like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionJdbcJob.xml

Comment: Yes, already tried that way too, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I am always avoiding xml configuration and trying to do as much in java as I can, maybe you can extend `JdbcCursorItemReader` and put `@BeforeStep` there which will read `code` from context and create sql query. At least you can place breakpoint and see what is inside your context.

Comment: with custom JdbcCursorItemReader and overriding sql approach as u explained above it works, but is it suggested approach? as "<property name="sql" value=""> is still mandatory in custom JdbcCursorItemReader.  Is it possible to override Datasource also as I need to override DS based on user requirement?

Comment: `AbstractCursorItemReader` which `JdbcCursorItemReader` extends has `setDataSource()` exposed so I do not see why you wold not be able to do so in `@BeforeStep`. I do not know about suggested approach but when working with strings as sql statements and injected values I would always choose that approach. What you can do is maybe create sql with `?` and use one of implementations of `PreparedStatementSetter` to pass wired values from context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your own class which extends `JdbcCursorItemReader`, make it `@StepScope` and add `@BeforeStep`.

```
@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    final String code = execution.getExecutionContext().getString("code");
    final String sql = buildSql(code); //method which creates sql statement
}
```

In it you have `StepExecution` and you can take variables you need which are in context to build your sql. Override `afterPropertiesSet()` to set `sql`, `rowMapper` and `dataSource`.

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    setSql(sql);
    setRowMapper(rowMapper);
    setDataSource(dataSource);
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

Having java code instead of xml should be always IMO preferred approach since you have code under your hands, you can debug and this way you avoid potential xml typing errors. Also that approach is testable.